# How can I get all pairwise correlations of a list of 2d matrices in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, correlation

**EDIT**: The question has been edited after accepting the answer, to make it (hopefully) clearer.

Given the 3d matrix `M(m, n, k)`, how do I calculate the 2d correlation matrix `M(k, k)` whose `(i, j)` entry is `corr(M(m, n, i), M(m, n, j))`.

### Layman's terms

For example, I have a 3d matrix `M(20, 20, 100)`, and I need a 2d matrix `M(100, 100)` which is a correlation matrix of each pairwise combination of `M(20, 20, i)`, where `i = 100`. Since `M(100, 100)` is a correlation matrix, each cell is a single correlation coefficient (`r`), and the matrix is symmetric:

```
     a     b     c    ...
a    1     r_ab  r_ac 
b    r_ba  1     r_bc
c    r_ca  r_cb  1
...
```

### Matlab MWE

I tried combinations of loops, `corrcoef`, `corr2`, with no avail.

```
% 3d matrix
m = rand(20, 20, 100);

% wrong output
r = corrcoef(m(:, :));
```

Comment: Yes, I mean the correlation between two matrices to be a single value (this might not be the correct terminology, sorry for that). If you post the comment as answer I can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to reshape `m` so that each matrix is linearized into a column. Then [`corrcoef`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) gives the desired result:

```
r = corrcoef(reshape(m, [], size(m,3)));
```